# Eclipse Logcat doesn't get update on the current filter (Android)

Tags: android, eclipse, logcat, android-logcat

I have this annoying problem, that Im pretty sure happens to all of you too.

I add a filter to the logacat in order to see message that belongs only to my application.
The problem is that the logcat doesn't get updated while im in the current filter (it happens for every filter, including "All Messages (no filter)" filter).

In order to see all the messages i've missed, I need to click on the filter with the mouse.

How to fix this??

thanks!

Comment: Why you'd create own filter. It'll automatically create. Then why you've created?

Comment: I have this problem too. It doesn't always happen. Just sometimes. And @SpK this happens to the automagically created filters too. In my case atleast. It's basically all or nothing. 50% chance it actually works/not works. :/ So a solution would be appreciated.

Comment: SpK I guess you're right about that thing, but it doesn't solve the problem.

Comment: I have also the same problem. actually eclipse full with annoying "bugs" such this one.

Comment: Are you connecting multiple device or multiple emulators there?

Comment: Okay. First, just restart your Workspace. And, goto `DDMS` there select your device. And, now try to run. I've done this all time, if i don't have the filter.

Comment: Not working in restarting. I got to check with my flagged log verbose code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unfortunately, this is a bug in eclipse or in the adb or logcat.   maybe other versions of eclipse beside "classic" won't suffer from that bug, such as Eclipse Indigo. worth trying